# Laravel 5.2 two Paypal REST API SDK account

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal-rest-sdk

How will I put two apicontext in my system? I already made a paypal rest api sdk in my system and it is running properly, Now I need to put another paypal account but I dont know how will I put it. How will I do this in laravel?

Comment: You want to use via different controller or same controller?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw Same controller.

Comment: One more question, which library you using for PayPal? Netshell?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw Paypal REST API SDK for PHP. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Comment: It can be done. But, it also depending in your business logic. E.g how you want want to break down your two paypal option.

Comment: @KelvinKyaw I want to seperate the account for the local and international, right now my local account of paypal is working, my problem is the international account, how will i put it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128609/discussion-between-kelvin-kyaw-and-ace).